# c# nullable arguments. Assign to null er use question mark?

Tags: c#, nullable

Hey i can't seem to find the answer to this question answered in a way that makes complete sense to me.

when declaring nullable arguments in c#, what is the difference between declaring a argument with a question mark like this:

```
public method(int? variable):
```

and with an assignment like this:

```
public method(int variable = null):
```

Comment: you can't do the second case without making `int` nullable.

Comment: well, i should have used a reference type instead of int, my mistake. i think what i dont understand is what the difference is between nullable and optional

Comment: Well the first one will compile. If you want to make the parameter `variable` optional with a default value of `null`, then you'd say `public method(int? variable = null):`

Comment: thanks flydog! but if i want it to be null at default, why do i need to add the question mark? it seems like it should be enough with just the assignment?

Comment: Value types (like int, other numeric types, enums and anything defined as a `struct`) are not normally nullable. To add `null` to the range of a value type variable, declare it as nullable (either `int?` or `Nullable<int>`). If you add a default expression to a parameter declaration for a method (like`(int? variable = null)`), then you are declaring the parameter to be optional. If the caller doesn't specify a value for that parameter at the call site, the parameter is considered to have its default value in the body of the method

Comment: ahhhh, I see. So i wouldnt need to use the question mark for a reference type? like string

Comment: Variables typed as reference types are nullable all on their own. Every variable has a `default` value (for example, the default for `int`s is zero). The default value for variables that are reference type is `null` (which signals that the variable refers to nothing). Value types always have a value associated with them. Nullable value types simple accept `null` as one of those values. The latest C# has *nullable reference types* which is a misnomer kind of. If you enable that feature, the ref type variables cannot be null unless they are described as accepting null as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first makes a required nullable `int` argument named variable. The second won't even compile.

If you were to do

```
public method(int? variable = null)
```

Then you could call `method` as `method()`, not passing a value for `variable` and `null` will be inserted by the compiler call which is the default value provided in the parameter.

Comment: Oh yes, I should have used a reference type in my example. My mistake.

Comment: Okay, I'm lost. I'm not saying I'd encourage the use of `int?`, but neither is this answer, necessarily. Why the downvotes?